# Are errors logged somewhere by default on Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, error-logging

I have a React Native mobile app on the Apple App Store and Google Play Store. A user observed an error while using the app, but they have since closed the app.

I was debugging locally and I couldn't reproduce the error. I don't see any errors in the API logs, so it appears to be a frontend app problem. Unfortunately, I haven't implemented any tools to monitor errors in the frontend.

Is there any way to see past errors that occurred in the frontend? Do they get logged somewhere by default - maybe on the apple.developer or android.developer portals?

Comment: This isn't practical for your case, but for Android you can [enable Developer options](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options#enable), enable USB debugging, connect the phone via USB to a computer with the Android SDK installed, then run [adb logcat](https://developer.android.com/tools/logcat) on the computer to view the Android logs (which should have the app's exception stack trace). Note that old messages are deleted when the log buffer fills up, so if it's been a while they may be gone (and obviously it's a massive hassle for an end-user to do all that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about seeing past errors, unfortunately.

For future occasions, [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) is a good framework for bug logging that has established support for [React Native](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/) and [Expo](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-sentry/), and it offers limited error and performance monitoring for free (source: [pricing page](https://sentry.io/pricing/)).